# Does Django's ConditionalGetMiddleware play nicely with multiple servers behind a load balancer?

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I read in a few places that if you're using etags you might run into issues if your app is horizontally scaled. Does Django's ConditionalGetMiddleware work out of the box if you run multiple app servers behind a load balancer?

Comment: Though I haven't done this myself - I would think that it should be ok since a lot of architectures are aligned that way. Maybe, consider asking the author of the article you are referring to.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't end up using etags, instead I used the Last-Modified header.